# Determining what commands will be run when using a makefile in C?

Tags: c, makefile

Right now I'm working on some practice questions for a computer science course. One of the ones I've encountered involves makefiles and goes as follows:

```
You are working in a directory which contains the following files and no others:
makefile     myscript     one.c     three.c     two.h
------------------------------------
Here are the contents of makefile:

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-ansi

myprogram: two.o three.o
 gcc -o myprogram two.o three.o

two.c: one.c myscript
 sed -rf myscript one.c >| two.c

three.o: two.h
------------------------------------

1.)  If you type `make myprogram` in this directory, what commands will be run?

2.)  After the commands are run, what new files will have been created?

3.)  After this, you edit `two.h` (and no other files) and then type make `myprogram` again. What
commands will be run?
```

So from my limited understanding of `Makefile` I know that for `1.)` the commands to be run would be `gcc -o myprogram two.o three.o` because `myprogram` does not exist in the directory. However, `two.o` and `three.o` do not exist either... This is where I get a bit lost, would I then run the command beneath `two.c: one.c myscript` because it does forced overwrite? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `three.o`

  There's a specific rule for `three.o`, so that explains where that `three.o` comes from.
- `two.o`

  `make` has lot of implicit rules: it knows (guesses) that if it finds a `*.c` file, it should compile it to an `*.o` file if there's no specific rule for it, or even go one step further and create an `a.out`/executable file.

  These implicit rules will work in the case of `two.o`, which has no specific rule, but `make` can deduce the rule from `two.c`.
- `three.o` (reprise)

  `make` can also make a good guess what the source file should be if it's not given: in the case of `three.o`, it will try and match that with `three.c`, which is the logical source file for that object file.  (`two.h` is just an additional dependency).

---

If you really want to know, create the exercise. This may be a tad difficult because of `myscript` and the `sed` command, but keep in mind that you can essentially create nearly empty source files (include guards in the header file would still be a good idea, so it can't accidentally get included twice).

Then, you could run `make` with the `-d` (debug) flag, or with the `-n` (no-op flag; don't do anything). The just go through steps 1, 2 and 3.

Of course, doing all this may *show* you what happens, but that doesn't have to mean you understand it. Combining this with what you know about Make, the above in this answer and the results you're getting from running the actual experiment should get you a long way though.

Comment: Okay, so would `two.o` and `three.o` be "made" because of the implicit rules of make?

Comment: `two.o` is in my answer; please read more carefully. `three.o` has a rule, but there's an implicit source file (so call it that Make uses a "partially implicit rule" for this).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll do my best to understand everything you've shown!

Answer (score 0):

Some make utilities have an option to display the commands that would be run, but without running them. For example for Linux and Unix make it's -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon. For Microsoft nmake, the option is /n.

If a script or batch file is involved, it could be more difficult.